# Streaming data to text files

Tags: console, streaming, windows-xp

I can stream viewable data in the Windows Console, I also stream the data into a text file using

`--raw>output.txt` as the command line

This text file will continue to grow in size as long as data is streaming. Is it possible to end streaming into the initial text file and start streaming into a second text file? Perhaps after 10 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [pipe operator](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) to redirect output to a tool that will perform required cutting. cutting can be implemented easily by yourself or probably you'll find something ready for use

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I can now write a bat file to stream the data to a txt file, I can use a ping command to provider a time delay (is this where sleep.exe would be useful?), but I can't exit the "someprogram --raw>output.txt" after the time delay, only ctrl-C in the console seems to stop the thing! Is there an edit to "someprogram --raw>output.txt" that exits the stream after n seconds? I can then command "someprogram --raw>output(n+1).txt" so the data will be stored in a series of files: output1, output2, output3 etc.

Comment: such timeout functionality should be provided by `someprogram`, in case of `ping` it would be `-n count` argument

Comment: Look like I need 15 reputation(s) to vote up. I'm sure there is timeout functionality in "someprogram" but I'm out of my depth when I look at the program files! Time delay I'm using is "ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1"

Comment: Making some progress, but a clumsy solution. Run two bat files concurrently, use "tskill someprogram" at intervals to kill "someprogram", restart "someprogram" but streaming to the next output.txt file. Some lost data but I'm looking at trends not individual measurements. I usually specify and procure sub-systems, assembling into systems, installing and commissioning on site; so working at this level is new experience!